# Calculating Eigenvalues in Numpy not Working: Each element is a float

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, linear-algebra

Trying to calculate the eigenvalues of a matrix for Newton Method optimisation.

Using Python 2.7.6 in PyDev for Eclipse.

This is the variable (Hessian) as returned from PyDev:

```
ndarray: [[ 0.01  0.  ]
[ 0.    1.  ]]
```

The following command:

```
np.linalg.eig(Hessian)
```

Returns the exception:

```
ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I've even tried converting each of the elements to a float value, by cycling through each element and using the `float` function.

EDIT/FURTHER INFO:Upon inserting `print repr(Hessian)` it yielded the following result.

```
array([[0.01, 0.0],
   [0.0, 1.0]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Can you show us both the traceback and the output of `print repr(your_array)`?

Comment: My apologies, I have since worked it out sorry. If I make it so that Hessian = array(Hessian,dtype=numpy.float32) it works now. I'll try and do the above for others though so they can get the specifics of the diagnosis. Unlucky/lucky quick fix sorry...

Comment: `print repr(Hessian)` output is now inserted at the bottom above.

Comment: Sounds like the Sympy processing is the problem. The number was still saved as a Sympy expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments it appears the matrix wasn't a numpy array, causing errors when working with numpy.

As you noted:

"Maybe it was this process of `Hessian[i,j]=diff(diff(function,x_i),x_j)` which caused the trouble."

I also can't reproduce your error.

The eigienvectors of a simple scale transform matrix like `[[0.01, 0.], [0., 1.]]` are clearly the standard basis vectors `[1,0]` and `[0,1]` by inspection, the eigenvalues 0.01 and 1.

The relevant numpy modules have no problem doing this, so the error must be elsewhere.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> M = np.array([[0.01,0.],[0.,1.]])
>>> M
array([[ 0.01,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  1.  ]])
>>> np.linalg.eig(M)
(array([ 0.01,  1.  ]), array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]]))
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have mentioned I recreated a similar instance in IDLE and it worked. The thing is I processed each element using Sympy to differentiate the function to create a Hessian matrix. Maybe it was this process of `Hessian[i,j]=diff(diff(function,x_i),x_j)` which caused the trouble.

Comment: Edit the solution to fit the info above and I'll accept it. Thanks for the info!